# How to generate sequential numbers using UCM Oracle iDOC Script?

Tags: oracle-ucm, idoc

I want to create a metadata field to a certain Check-In Profile. This field is Info Only and it looks like this:

```
IFAP-XXXX.DD.MMM/YY
```

I already have done this code:

```
<$dprDefaultValue="IFAP-" & formatDateWithPattern(dateCurrent(),"MMM/yy")$>
```

And the output is: `IFAP-.01Jan/16`

What I need is to put a sequential number where "XXXX" is, starting with `0800`, every time a user checks in.  For example: `IFAP-0801.01.Jan/16`.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Getting a unique sequence number can be challenging. One way would be to write a custom service that executes a query against the database (which controls the sequence) and responds with the number. You could then executeService("MY_CUSTOM_SEQUENCE_SERVICE")$> to get the value.

One of the issues with the above approach is what happens if the checkin fails (due to a filter or something else). Then you have accidentally used up a value.

Another approach would be to use a database trigger to replace XXXX with the sequence number (using the same database sequence number).